# How to display ticket list in all pages of WHMCS?

Tags: variables, templates, twitter-bootstrap-3, whmcs

I'm designing a bootstrap theme for **WHMCS**, and in top navigation (located in **header.tpl**), there is a button which onClick, it shows a floating window consist of list of tickets with a custom scroll.

The problem is: in "**clientarea.php**" and "**supporttickets.php**" pages it works correctly, but *in other pages, although it shows the number of tickets, but is not showing the list view of tickets*.

Thanks. Code:

```
{if $loggedin} {if in_array('tickets',$contactpermissions)}
                    <li class="xn-icon-button pull-right">
                        <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-comments"></span></a>
                        <div class="informer informer-danger"> {$clientsstats.numactivetickets}</div>
                        <div class="panel panel-primary animated zoomIn xn-drop-left xn-panel-dragging">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="panel-title" style="font-size: 13pt;"> {$LANG.supportticketsopentickets} <span class="fa fa-comments"></span></h3>                                
                                <div class="pull-left">
                                    <span class="label label-danger"> Tickets:  {$clientsstats.numactivetickets}</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="panel-body list-group list-group-contacts scroll" style="height: 200px;">
{foreach from=$tickets item=ticket}                         
                                <a href="viewticket.php?tid={$ticket.tid}&amp;c={$ticket.c}" class="list-group-item">
                                    <div class="list-group-status status-online"></div>
                                    <img src="templates/{$template}/assets/images/users/dadparvar.jpg" class="pull-right" alt="Hamed Azimi"/>
                                    <span class="contacts-title">{$ticket.department}: <i>{$ticket.status}</i></span>
                                    <p>{if $ticket.unread}<strong>{/if}#{$ticket.tid} - {$ticket.subject}{if $ticket.unread}</strong>{/if}
                                    </p>
                                </a>
{foreachelse}
{$LANG.supportticketsnoneopen}
{/foreach}                                                          
                            </div> 

                            <div class="panel-footer text-center">
                                <a href="submitticket.php">{$LANG.opennewticket}</a> | <a href="supporttickets.php">Show all tickets</a>
                            </div>                            
                        </div>                        
                    </li>
{/if}{/if}
```

Comment: Simply the question is that "how can I show tickets list in **all pages** in WHMCS?". any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are available on the mentioned pages because WHMCS is already loading them for you. In the pages that tickets aren't available use WHMCS API function to load them in a variable with same structure you use in the template.

[Get Tickets api function docs](http://docs.whmcs.com/API:Get_Tickets)

```
{php}
$client_id = $this->get_template_vars('clientsdetails.id');
$results = localAPI('gettickets', array('clientid' => $client_id), 'admin');
if ($results['result'] == 'success') {
    $tickets = $results['tickets']['ticket'];
}
$this->assign('tickets', $tickets);
{/php}
```

Add this code in the top of TPL file you want view tickets list.

Notes:

- Code still lacks some required funcitons, like checking for tickets access permission and department name, you can check the WHMCS API or query database directly.
- You can use smarty includes to add the code in one file and just include it when required.